# Apache: How to set different root folder depending whether user local or from outside network

Tags: macos, apache

I have a root directory `/Users/username/Sites/` that I use to test sites locally. I want to expose only one of the subfolders `Users/username/Sites/subsite` to requests that come from outside the network.

I already have port forwarding setup and I'm able to see the root directory when I log from my dynamic DNS service.

What do I have to do to Apache to have this work? I've tried several searches but I can't seem to come up with the right wording to get an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could create (or modify) a `<VirtualHost>` in the server config that accepts requests for the "dynamic-dns-hostname.example" that points directly at `Users/username/Sites/subsite`.

For example, the bare minimum would be (copy the config from your existing vHost):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dynamic-dns-hostname.example
    DocumentRoot Users/username/Sites/subsite
    <Directory Users/username/Sites/subsite>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This effectively *hides* the name of the `/subsite` directory from the user since a request for `http://dynamic-dns-hostname.example/` points directly to the subdirectory.

This is only HTTP (port 80). If you are allowing HTTPS connections then you will need another vHost for port 443 (default) with all the SSL config.

---

Alternatively, you could issue an external redirect (or internal rewrite if you want to *hide* the subdirectory) when accessing `Users/username/Sites` for any IP that is not a local IP address.

For example, in your main vHost container (or `<Directory /Users/username/Sites>` container, or `.htaccess` file in the `/Users/username/Sites/` directory) you could do something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[^/]+/subsite($|/)
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /subsite/$1 [R,L]
```

This assumes that local IP addresses start `192.168.`

---

*Aside:*

Instead of creating a new subdirectory (in a single vHost) for each subsite you create, it would be preferable to create a new vHost for each subsite and have this point to a separate directory (not a subdirectory) so there is no overlap.

If this was the case then it would simply be a matter of adding a `ServerAlias` directive to the appropriate vHost container:

```
ServerAlias dynamic-dns-hostname.example
```